# Min=1 max=30 throws error - HTML Textbox

Tags: html

I have this textbox, I would like to allow only numbers from 1 to 40 in the textbox, the problem is it throws an error only for numbers in between 2 to9

```
    <input type="number" min="1" max="40" maxlength="2"
 class="form-control hcount" name="hcount" id="hcount" />
```

[image]

Comment: There is obviously more than just this, post the code for the error validation

Comment: @there might be some jquery validation you have to check that